# PHP session only stores when explicitly requested on each page

Tags: php, variables, session

I am a PHP noob. I have this code at the top of all my pages and is meant to store currency when selected via GET link.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['currency'])) {
$_SESSION['currency'] = $_GET['currency'];
}

?>
```

I also use the following on all pages to display the selected currency (use USD if currency is not selected):

```
<?php print isset($_SESSION['currency']) ? "{$_SESSION['currency']}" : 'usd'; ?>
```

But the session only seems to be setting currency on the page where I have selected it. Let's say I select EUR on index.php and then navigate to page2.php - but it will show USD. If I go back to index.php, it's still saved as EUR, but I need all pages to save EUR if I have selected it on one of the other pages.

I place session_start at the top of every page, my encoding is UTF-8 without BOM, no errors showing and I force https and www so that it's always seen as one and the same site.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get my session to save throughout the site? The site is running PHP 7.4 if that helps

Comment: Start by making a debug output of `session_id()` on top of each page (after you started the session), to verify whether the session ID stays the same, or if a new one gets created every time. _“If I go back to index.php, it's still saved as EUR”_ - is it actually still saved in the session, or does “going back” mean you click a link with `?currency=eur` again (which would _put_ the value into the session again then, regardless of whether it was the same or a new session)?

Comment: Strangely, only index.php returns a session ID although all pages contain the same codes. I have double checked. To answer your question, when I go back to the page where I selected the currency, I don't need to use GET. But It seems that no other page is saving session. Spooky and annoying...

Comment: `session_id()` returns an empty string, if there is no active session. Sounds like picking up the session again did not work to begin with in those other files then. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['currency'])) {
$_SESSION['currency'] = $_GET['currency'];
}

?>
```

On top of all of your pages and you don't pass currency as query param, then on every page you will be replacing the session with empty **$_GET['currency']**

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php erro_reporting(0);
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['currency'])) {
$_SESSION['currency'] = $_GET['currency'];
}
echo $_SESSION['currency']!="" ? $_SESSION['currency'] : "USD";
?>
```